# UITextChecker code not giving correct result

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui, sprite-kit

I am using the standard method I think to check a word for validity. I have a 4 part array that is joined to make the word being verified.
I have this placed in my `touches began func` in a SpriteKit scene however it always gives me the answer "CORRECT SPELLING" even when it is not.

Curiously when I put the exact same bit of code into my `did move to view func` so it runs when the game starts it works perfectly well. The code is exactly the same except instead of the joined array I just create a `let word = "WORD"`  before the code. So I am guessing the problem must be something to do with my joined array??

This is my code

```
 let word = wordArray.joined()
        
        let textChecker = UITextChecker()
        let misspelledRange = textChecker.rangeOfMisspelledWord(
            in: word, range: NSRange(0..<word.utf16.count), startingAt: 0, wrap: false, language: "en_US")

                if misspelledRange.location != NSNotFound,
                   let guesses = textChecker.guesses(
                    forWordRange: misspelledRange, in: word, language: "en_US")
                {
                    print("Guess: \(String(describing: guesses.first))") //Output is: Guess: Optional("Tester")

                } else {
                    print("\(word) CORRECT SPELLING")
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Turned out my issue was that UITextChecker does not like full caps!
Only accepts lower case spellings